# Gtk.EntryCompletion() popup status to resolve keybind conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have the **Gtk.Entry()** with **Gtk.EntryCompletion()**, have binded the arrows key to do different function i.e. navigate through the command history like in terminal.

But   navigation on **Completion Popup** will, conflict with history navigation, Is there any way to check if **Completion Popup** is visible/active, so that we can turn of history navigation.

Plus, Is there way to get total match count of **Completion Popup**.

Below is the sample program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk

entry = Gtk.Entry()

def on_key_press(widget, event):
    # NOTE to stop propagation of signal return True
    if   event.keyval == 65362: widget.set_text("history -1") # Up-arrow
    elif event.keyval == 65364: widget.set_text("history +1") # Down-arrow

entry.connect('key_press_event', on_key_press)

entrycompletion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
entry.set_completion(entrycompletion)

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
for row in "entry complete key conflit with history".split():
    liststore.append([row])

entrycompletion.set_model(liststore)
entrycompletion.set_text_column(0)

root = Gtk.Window()
root.add(entry)
root.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
root.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the inline selection option to `True` with `entrycompletion.set_inline_selection(True)`. This will connect the key press event to the completion pop-up menu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk

entry = Gtk.Entry()

def on_key_press(widget, event):
    # NOTE to stop propagation of signal return True
    if   event.keyval == 65362: widget.set_text("history -1") # Up-arrow
    elif event.keyval == 65364: widget.set_text("history +1") # Down-arrow

entry.connect('key_press_event', on_key_press)

entrycompletion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
entrycompletion.set_inline_selection(True) #enables selection with up and down arrows
entry.set_completion(entrycompletion)

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
for row in "entry complete key conflit with history".split():
    liststore.append([row])

entrycompletion.set_model(liststore)
entrycompletion.set_text_column(0)

root = Gtk.Window()
root.add(entry)
root.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
root.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this problem was so frustrating not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Finally solved it completely, now I can sleep in Peace.

Had the problem of losing the focus of entry when there was **no-matches**, if I stop the propagation of the signal, the autocomplete suggestion couldn't be navigated if I did focus got lost from the Entry.

Since **cursor-on-match** signal only  after user defined **key_press_event**.

Solved it using **focus** signal from **Gtk.Widget**